# ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation

Tags: python, opencv

I was just finished compiling opencv2 using visual studio and CMake, i finished building the library and was about to test it in my cmd prompt and i got this error.

Here is a the error:

```
site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\Talla\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Talla\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Talla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\Talla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 152, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "C:\Users\Talla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Talla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\Talla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 75, in bootstrap
    raise ImportError('ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.')
ImportError: ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.
>>>
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: It looks live you have accidentally stumbled upon https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13202 , there are some trouble shooting steps mentioned there as well, but I dont think there is a direct recovery from this.

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution after some digging.

This fixed it:
pip3 install opencv-python --upgrade --force-reinstall # [--user]

Comment: What does "# [--user]" do? It says invalid requirement when I try on windows cmd