# ImportError: ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation

Tags: python, opencv, importerror, pyautogui

I as making a screen recorder with python and I was using OpenCV with python but its giving this output that I can't find a working answer ANYWHERE and I really need help. I am have only been using python for about a year. Here is the output it gives me:

```
['C:\\Users\\Diana\\Desktop\\python\\RecScreen', 'C:\\Users\\Diana\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Diana\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Diana\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Diana\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310', 'C:\\Users\\Diana\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Diana\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\pygooglevoice-0.5-py3.10.egg', 'C:\\Users\\Diana\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\Diana\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Diana\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Diana\Desktop\python\RecScreen\RecScreen.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Users\Diana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\cv2\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\Diana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\cv2\__init__.py", line 75, in bootstrap
    raise ImportError('ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.')
ImportError: ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.
```

My code is:

```
# importing the required packages
import pyautogui
import cv2
import keyboard
import numpy as np

# Specify resolution
resolution = (1920, 1080)

# Specify video codec
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")

# Specify name of Output file
filename = "Recording.avi"

# Specify frames rate. We can choose any
# value and experiment with it
fps = 60.0


# Creating a VideoWriter object
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, fps, resolution)

cv2.namedWindow("Recording", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Recording", 480, 270)

while True:
    # Take screenshot using PyAutoGUI
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()

    # Convert the screenshot to a numpy array
    frame = np.array(img)

    # Convert it from BGR(Blue, Green, Red) to
    # RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Write it to the output file
    #out.write(frame)
    
    # Optional: Display the recording screen
    cv2.imshow('Live', frame)
    
    # Stop recording when we press 'ctrl+esc'
    if keyboard.is_pressed("Ctrl+esc"):
        break

# Release the Video writer
out.release()

# Destroy all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I can't figure out how to fix this error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70366500/error-recursion-is-detected-during-loading-of-cv2-binary-extensions-check-op)

it worked for me
put this in your cmd as you run as admin

```
pip3 install opencv-python --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Comment: It still is giving me the error. If it would help you, the output is in the link.
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U7i3xz9M12scYBn648VH-s9mwubb2BR6/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U7i3xz9M12scYBn648VH-s9mwubb2BR6/view?usp=sharing)